# SSD - Help to identify write issue

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ssd

I have been given a new computer from my employer.

It has a 2-drive design: a 128GB ssd and a 1 TB HDD.

I have 'download' folder mounted on HDD, also my virtualbox VMs run from HDD but initially (for about 2 weeks) were runing from SSD.

**How it's possible it reached more than 30 TiB written in just a month?**

**Actually 34500 GiB in 365 hours.**

PC is HP-Pavillon 16GiB of RAM and drives as above

I just left it as it was 'out of the box' editing just this:
  pagefile -> was on C: (Now I moved on D: that is HDD)
  Download folder -> moved also to D (via windows utility)
  Virtualbox-> installed on C (first machines were created there), once I ran out of space I moved (with Virtualbox utility) to D also.

I noticed that few machines still keep their snapshots on C even if migrated on D with Vbox tool.

In virtualbox I have 20VMs

SSD drive status: [image: ssd status]

EDIT:
Crystal Disk Mark also reports 0x86E9 in 'lifetime writes from host'

Comment: We'll need much more information on this issue to give you any idea whats happened... Please can you let us know more about the problem? screenshots and setup descriptions are ideal.

Comment: Edited to add more data. Which config files you'd like to have?

Comment: Where is this 30TiB being written?

Comment: Added crystaldiskinfo screenshot to original post (scritture totali su host = total disk writes)

Comment: Ok, I understand the question now...

Comment: Updated: screenshot now in english

Comment: I'm just calculating this out, and it works out to be roughly 40 Gbits an hour. A back of envelope calculation indicates on a 100Mbit connection, you can download around 28Gbytes an hour, in ideal conditions. If you are shifting large volumes of data around on your VM's I can easily see how you'd write 30TiB in a month.

Comment: I'm not shifting much data: I have multiple VMs to test various ldap configurations, so I'm not transfering much data (few KiB of data transferred from server vm to client to prove ldap is working). I also didn't thing 'running' a VM will eat that much of data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89549/discussion-between-stese-and-dds).

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual SMART values are not visible in your screenshot because they’re further down. I’m pretty sure this is merely an error in the SMART data or their interpretation.

Comment: If reported correctly it reports  0x86E9 in 'lifetime writes from host'

Comment: FanSpeed reports 86F3 as 'total LBA written'

Comment: That’s not even 17 GiB (0x86F3 LBAs * 512 Byte/LBA). I don’t know how CrystalDiskMark arrives at this value.

Comment: This still don't make sense because my SSD is filled for 90GiB. This means that at least 90GiBs were written. Also `0x86F3 * 512B = 0x10D E600 B ~= 16 MiB` (an absurd again)